# Download PDF Angular JS from MVC (return File)

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

This code works without using angular only MCV  but when I return the file to Angular JS doesnt work download the pdf on the browser. I think the problem is on

```
generateForm(contactId: number, remarks: string): void {
        this.orderFactory.generateForm(this.$stateParams['orderId'], this.$stateParams['priority'], contactId, remarks).then((response) =>
```

I test many ways but i dont know. How I need to do ??

```
public class CoverVM
{
public int? OrderId { get; set; }
public int? Priority{ get; set; }
public int? ContactId { get; set; }
public string Remarks { get; set; }
}
```

MCV Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Cover(CoverVM Model)
{
  Order order = db.Orders.Find(Model.OrderId);
  var location = order.OrderLocations.Where(p => p.LocationPriority == Model.Priority).FirstOrDefault();
  var opposing = order.OrderCounsils.FirstOrDefault();
  var otherdelivery = order.OrderOtherDeliveries.FirstOrDefault();
  var AttachmentFiles = order.AttachmentFiles.FirstOrDefault();
  if (order != null)
  {
    string fileName = order.OrderNo.HasValue ? "Cover"+ order.OrderNo.Value.ToString() : "Cover";
    fileName += (Model.Priority + "-" + Model.ContactId + ".pdf");
    var pdfPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Forms/Reports"), "Cover.pdf");
    if (order!= null){
      try { 
       .........
      }  
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
     Debug.Print(ex.ToString()); 
     }
     finally
    {
     stamper.Close();
     }
     return File(outPutFilePath, "application/pdf", fileName);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Angular view **Cover.html**

```
    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
        <label>Delivery To {{vm.deliveryPartyId}}</label>
        <md-icon md-svg-icon="communication:location_on" title="{{vm.deliveryParties.id}}"></md-icon>
        <md-select ng-model="vm.deliveryPartyId" name="contactId" required ng-change="vm.onPartySelect(vm.deliveryPartiesId)">
            <md-optgroup label="{{currentGroup}}" ng-repeat="currentGroup in vm.deliveryGroups">
                <md-option ng-repeat="party in vm.deliveryParties  | filter: {group: currentGroup}"
                           ng-value="party.id" ng-disabled="{{party.disabled}}">
                    {{party.title}}
                </md-option>
            </md-optgroup>
        </md-select>
     </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm="50">
        <label>Additional Information</label>
        <textarea ng-model="vm.remarks" rows="5" md-maxlength="256" name="remarks"></textarea>
    </md-input-container>

    <md-button aria-label="Generate Cover PDF" ng-click="vm.generateForm(vm.deliveryPartyId, vm.remarks)" ng-disabled="!vm.deliveryPartyId">
        <md-icon md-svg-icon=""></md-icon> Generate Cover PDF
    </md-button>
```

Angular Controller **cover.controller.ts**

```
module app.order.admin {
    'use strict';
export class CoverController {
    reportWcab: IOrder;
    title: string;
    locations: IOrderLocation;
    deliveryParties: Array<any>;
    deliveryGroups: Array<any>;
    remarks: string;
    data: any;

    static $inject = ['$state', '$stateParams', 'orderFactory', 'toastAlert', '$scope'];

    constructor(
        private $state: ng.ui.IStateService,
        private $stateParams: ng.ui.IStateParamsService,
        private orderFactory: app.order.IOrderAdminFactory,
        private toastAlert: app.IToastAlert,
        private $scope: any
    ) {
    ............................
```

........................................

```
generateForm(contactId: number, remarks: string): void {
        this.orderFactory.generateForm(this.$stateParams['orderId'], this.$stateParams['priority'], contactId, remarks).then((response) => {

             // What can I to do download the pdf?? 
          //  window.location.href = "/Form/Cover/?Model=" + this.data;


            console.log('response', response);
            this.toastAlert.showToaster("ok");
        });

    }
 } angular
    .module('app.order.admin')
    .controller('ReportController', CoverController);
 }
```

On OrderFactory

```
generateForm(orderId: number, priority: number, contactId: number, remarks: string): ng.IPromise<any> {
            var data = {
                OrderId: orderId,
                Priority: priority,
                ContactId: contactId,
                Remarks: remarks || ''
            };
            return this.$http.post('/Form/Cover', data).then(this.handleSuccess, this.handleError);
         }
```

Comment: Works, but it doesn't... can you explain yourself a little bit more?

Comment: without using angular only MCV but when I return the file to Angular JS no works download the pdf on the browser.. I dont know how to to for download the pdf.

Comment: Yeah, that is because of your are using an async call to get the pdf...that way is not going to work...try with a hidden `<a href` and triggering a click on it :)

Comment: in that case how can I pass the Object on href??

Comment: You can pass the properties of the model via get!

Comment: Could you show how an example please??

Comment: Also you can create a form object and add input type hidden on it...set the data for each input and trigger the submit method....you just ned to get rid of the the line `return this.$http.post` and update the logic based on the comments....